# TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator when concatenating csv files

Tags: python, csv, pandas, concatenation, glob

l have a set of csv files to concatenate. To do so, l wrote a function to do the job. however l find my final csv (which groups all the csv) with duplicated header in the two first rows then duplicated header each time it concatenates a new csv.

as follow :

```
    from_line   all_chars_in_the_same_row   page_number words   char    left    top right   bottom
    from_line   all_chars_in_same_row   page_number words   char    left    top right   bottom
0   0   ['m', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'u', 'i', 'l', 'i', 'l']  1841729699_001  [[mi, il, mu, il, il]]  m   38  104 2456    2492
1   0   ['m', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'u', 'i', 'l', 'i', 'l']  1841729699_001  [[mi, il, mu, il, il]]  i   40  102 2442    2448
```

then when concatenating it with a new csv file :

```
2048    49  ['L', 'A', 'C', 'H', 'E', 'T', 'E', 'U', 'R', 'D', 'Ã‰', 'C', 'L', 'A', 'R', 'E', 'A', 'V', 'O', 'I', 'R', 'P', 'R', 'I', 'S', 'C', 'O', 'N', 'N', 'A', 'I', 'S', 'S', 'A', 'N', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'S', 'C', 'O', 'N', 'D', 'I', 'T', 'I', 'O', 'N', 'S', 'G', 'Ã‰', 'N', 'Ã‰', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'E', 'S', 'D', 'E', 'V', 'E', 'N', 'T', 'E', 'S', 'T', 'I', 'P', 'U', 'L', 'Ã‰', 'E', 'S', 'A', 'U', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'S', 'O', '.'] 1841729699_001  [[lacheteur, declare, avoir, pris, connaissance, des, conditions, generales, de, vente, stipulees, au, verso.]] 0   2364    2366    3426    3429
    from_line   all_chars_in_same_row   page_number words   char    left    top right   bottom
0   0   ['m', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'u', 'i', 'l', 'i', 'l']  1841729699_001  [[mi, il, mu, il, il]]  m   38  104 2456    2492
1   0   ['m', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'u', 'i', 'l', 'i', 'l']  1841729699_001  [[mi, il, mu, il, il]]  i   40  102 2442    2448
```

and so one. my function is as follow :

```
import os
import glob
import pandas

def concatenate(indir="files",outfile="concatenated.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=[" ","from_line","all_chars_in_the_same_row","page_number","words","char","left","top","right","bottom"]
    for filename in fileList:

        print(filename)
        df=pandas.read_csv(filename,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList,axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile,index=None)
```

To avoid duplicated header in the two first rows and headers each time it concatenates new files l added :

```
header = next(filename)
```

as follow :

```
import os
import glob
import pandas

def concatenate(indir="files",outfile="concatenated.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=[" ","from_line","all_chars_in_the_same_row","page_number","words","char","left","top","right","bottom"]
    for filename in fileList:

        print(filename)
        header=next(filename)# l got an error in this line
        df=pandas.read_csv(header,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList,axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile,index=None)
```

l got the following error:

```
  File "<input>", line 13, in concatenate
TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
```

**EDIT1**
after doing these changes

```
import os
import glob
import pandas

def concatenate(indir="files",outfile="concatenated.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=[" ","from_line","all_chars_in_the_same_row","page_number","words","char","left","top","right","bottom"]
    for filename in fileList:

        print(filename)
        with open(filename) as f:
             header=next(f)
             df = pandas.read_csv(header, header=None)
             dfList.append(df)
    concatDf = pandas.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    concatDf.columns = colnames
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
```

l got the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 15, in concatenate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 373, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:4184)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 667, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:8449)
FileNotFoundError: File b',from_line,all_chars_in_same_row,page_number,words,char,left,top,right,bottom\n' does not exist

**EDIT2**
```

after running this code l got the two firts columns duplicated

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

fileList=glob.glob("file*.csv")
colNames=[" ","from_line","all_chars_in_the_same_row","page_number","words","char","left","top","right","bottom"]

final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=colNames)
for fileName in fileList:
    df=pd.read_csv(fileName,skiprows=0) # skip first row w/ headers since you want to set column names yourself
    df.columns = colNames

    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df], axis=0)


print(final_df)





        from_line
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   2   0
3   3   0
4   4   0
5   5   0
6   6   0
7   7   0
8   8   0
9   9   0
10  10  1
11  11  1
12  12  2
```

however in the original csv files l have this :

```
    from_line
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to remove first column, which is a redundant index column.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
os.chdir('/home/max')

fileList=glob.glob("file*.csv")
colNames=["redundant_index_column","from_line","all_chars_in_the_same_row","page_number"]#,"words","char","left","top","right","bottom"]

final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=colNames)
for fileName in fileList:
    df=pd.read_csv(fileName,skiprows=0)
    df.columns = colNames

    print(df)
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)


final_df = final_df.drop(['redundant_index_column'], axis=1)

print(final_df)
```

Comment: it works but the first column is duplicated as follow :    from_line
0 0 0
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 3 0
4 4 0
5 5 0
6 6 0
7 7 0
8 8 0
9 9 0
10 10 1
11 11 1
12 12 2

Comment: do you mean your first column shows up as two columns? I tested this with a few arbitrary 3-line CSVs and that didn't happen in my test. Can you elaborate?

Comment: l gave a sample of my csv files and the finale concatenated csv file. yes the first column is duplicated . it's this column in colnames=[" ",

Comment: thanks for clarifying. that's not a repeat of the first column. The first "column" you're seeing is the pandas row-index.

Comment: Can l disable it ? because these files are processed before with pandas. so l need just to keep one column index of pandas

Comment: "disable" it in what context? Do you mean when you export to a new csv, you don't want the index to show up in the new exported csv?

Comment: l mean in this context. keep juste one column rather than 2 duplicated columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141451/discussion-between-max-power-and-vincent).

Answer (score 0):

glob.glob returns list of strings of filenames for a given regex in a given folder.
A string object is not an iterator, however, a file is (its a generator).

Try opening a file with:
f = open(filename)

your code will look like that:

```
fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
for filename in fileList:
    with open(filename) as f:
        header = next(f)
        ...
```

Note that there are many other problems with this code
in style and better approaches. But as for the error this should fix it

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

file_list=glob.glob("file*.csv")
col_names=[" ","from_line","all_chars_in_the_same_row","page_number","words","char","left","top","right","bottom"]

final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)
for filename in file_list:
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=0)
    df.columns = col_names

    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df], axis=0)

# print all
...
```

Comment: @Solo, l don't see your code. But l need an iterator since l have a set of csv files to concatenate. how can f=open(filename) go through all the csv files

Comment: "A string object is not iterable" <- A string *is* an iterable, but a string is not an iterator.

Comment: @timgeb: Correct. Excuse me for the wording I will edit the answer